# Get file URL from webloc file after drag drop using javascript on client side

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drag-and-drop

If I drag and drop a file on to a web application that I am working on, I would like to detect that if it is a webloc file, and in that case, extract the URL. At this point, I have gotten to the point where I have the file name and some file metadata from the data transfer object.

I would like to get the URL encoded within the .webloc file (apparently an xml file). Is there a Javascript or Angular or jQlite utility function that provides such a functionality? I would prefer to avoid jQuery or other frameworks if possible.